# FF factor benchmarks

Tags: factor-models, fama-french

I have a question to think about. I have constructed a portfolio of AMEX/NYSE/NASDAQ firms. After some data manipulation and cleaning I am left with some 4000 firms over the complete sample (max 1600 at the same time). I have excluded firms I do not have some observations for the variable I seek to examine.

Subsequently I have constructed two benchmark portfolio (EW and VW) with these respective firms. Thereafter, I regressed the fama-french-carhart factors upon these portfolios (MKT, SMB, HML, RMW, CMA, UMD).

Now my qeustion comes: How would you expect the Loadings (beta's) to behave? If I would have replicated their benchmark portfolio in the most acurate way possible. I would expect the loadings to be highly significant and close to to 1. Would that be correct? Or is that to narrow-minded.

By your knowledge are there any papers that examine the factor exposures of benchmark portfolios constructed in similar manner with similar firms as Fama and french (1992)

Hope to hear your thoughts.

Comment: If your portfolio is the benchmark, then aside from estimation error, you should have a market beta of 1 and all other factor loadings be identical to zero.

Comment: Alright. Makes sense.